# Python Docx add output of simple math equation

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx

How do I add the output of a simple math equation to my docx doc?

For example

```
math = 2+2

math
```

add_paragraph can only do strings and not integers. Is there a work around for this?

```
p = document.add_paragraph(math)
document.save('doc.docx')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use casting

```
math_string = str(math)
p = document.add_paragraph(math_string)
document.save('doc.docx')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add a complex formula using the math2docx library

```
import math2docx
from docx import Document

document = Document()
p = document.add_paragraph()

#LaTex Math Formula
latex_ = r"\cos (2\theta) = \cos^2 \theta - \sin^2 \theta"

math2docx.add_math(p, latex_ )
document.save("new_file.docx")
```

https://github.com/keh9mark/math2docx

Answer (score 0):

Convert the int to a string maybe?

```
p = document.add_paragraph(str(math))
```